# 50 Celsius degrees on Intel Xeon when idle - is it normal?

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure, cooling, temperature

I have recently assembled a PC with XEON E3-1230v3 (with factory cooling fan) on Asrock B85 Pro4 Intel B85  motherboard. What surprised me is that when idle (in BIOS)  the CPU temperature exceeds 50 Celsius degrees (usually it is about 52 degrees).

Is it normal? Also, is there a software which allows me to measure and set 'failsafe' temperature which will force shutdown after exceeding certain temperature on one of the components?

Comment: It is normal. Relax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the temperature is within "acceptable" range.  For comparison, my Raspberry Pi idles at around 42C, while servers at my place of work run at around 55-60C.

As for software, the manual (available via the Asrock site) indicates that the over-temperature setting, as well as the temperature triggers for the fan speeds, is configurable.

For the manual, see: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85%20Pro4/?cat=Manual